# How to get current datetime of a specific timezone using the IANA timezone identifier?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs, luxon

I am currently developing an app that (among other things) should display the current `datetime` of specific timezones using the IANA timezone identifiers as input. I came across the [Luxon library](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html) and I tried to use it in the following way:

```
DateTime.local().setZone(*IANA_identifier*)
```

However, besides timezones starting with `Etc/GMT..` I receive `null` as output (e.g. for `'America/New_York'`). So whether I am doing something wrong with the way I use Luxon or it is just not possible to achieve it with this library.

Could somebody tell me how I may tweak my code to make it work with the luxon library or point me to a library that is capable of returning the current `datetime` using an IANA timezone identifier as input?

Comment: Is that an actual timezone? Maybe have an array that translates to what you want on the other end?

Comment: @GetSet Please see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: Again doesnt seem as javascript would be *forward compatible* to any such new standard. Could you define an array?

Comment: @GetSet I just found a way (see my answer)

Comment: If that solves you use case then you all good.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing it. The [`moment-timezone`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) library can be used in the following way:

```
moment().tz('America/New_York').format() //2020-02-11T22:01:09-05:00
```

Comment: `DateTime.local().setZone('America/New_York').toISO()` works fine form me: `2020-02-11T22:22:46.210-05:00`. I used the [*browser setup*](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/install.html) and `var DateTime = luxon.DateTime;`. Luxon is bigger than moment.js, but to do this with moment the timezone library and data must also be installed. I think Luxon is supposed to be a better technical alternative to moment.js.

Comment: What happens if you do not add `.toISO()`?

Comment: @RobG I just found out that sometimes the IANA timezones are not supported with Luxon, which is the case for me. [See here](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/zones.html#iana-support)

Comment: Ah, Ok. BTW, IANA uses "representative locations" like 'America/New_York', which are distinct from timezones, though everyone calls them "IANA timezones". The reason is that each timezone covers many different administrative areas which may (and often do) have different historic offsets, particularly with respect to daylight saving. The "setZone" method would be better named "setOffsetRules" or "setRepresentativeLoc". ;-)